# populate previous value if key combination is null if no value then populate null

Tags: sql, teradata

input

```
key1 key 2 date
A    B     1/1/2018
A    B      NULL
A    C     2/2/2018
A    C      NULL
A   A       NULL
```

Out put:

```
key 1 key 2   date
A    B     1/1/2018
A    B      1/1/2018
A    C     2/2/2018
A    C      2/2/2018
A   A       NULL
```

Comment: I am using Teradata and trying add a logic with in sql

Comment: use `order by date desc`

Answer (score 2):

Filling NULLs with the previously existing value is simple with `last_value`:

```
select key1,key2,
   LAST_VALUE(date IGNORE NULLS)
   OVER (ORDER BY key1,key2) 
from mytab
```

You might want to do this for each `key1`:

```
select key1,key2,
   LAST_VALUE(date IGNORE NULLS)
   OVER (PARTITION BY key1
         ORDER BY key2) 
from mytab
```

Edit: Based on your example data, `key1` and `key2` are the same, in that case it might be

```
select key1,key2,
   MAX(date)
   OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2) 
from mytab
```

Comment: key 1 and key2 both are different . If key combination has having 2 records 1 with date and 1 with null then null should populate with date. if the both the key combination is null then I want to keep the NULL don't want to use the previous key combination value

Comment: If both keys are the same over multiple rows the `MAX` query should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a subquery that gets the max, assuming your *previous* is the max date for the key combination:

```
select key1,key2,coalesce(date,maxdate) as date
from mytab
join(
    select key1,key2,max(date) as maxdate 
    from mytab 
    group by key1,key2
    ) m on m.key1=mytab.key1 and m.key2=m.key2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here...

```
-----------------------------Create dummy table----------------------------------
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    [key_1]    VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [key_2]    VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [date]     DATE NULL 
);

-----------------------------Insert dummy data----------------------------------
INSERT  @MyTable ([key_1], [key_2], [date])
SELECT 'A', 'B', '1/1/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'B', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'C', '2/2/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'C', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'A', NULL  ;

-----------------------------Update table--------------------------------------
UPDATE MT_1 
SET MT_1.[date] = 
    (SELECT MAX(MT_2.date) 
    FROM @MyTable AS MT_2 
    WHERE MT_1.key_1 = MT_2.key_1 AND MT_1.key_2 = MT_2.key_2) 
FROM @MyTable AS MT_1

------------------------------Output Result------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```